# Designing React application for initial authorization based properties?

Tags: servlets, reactjs, permissions, http-headers, authorization

I have a user interface I'm designing that is expected to have multiple users of different authorization levels with varying levels of access to the UI.

I'm at a loss though for what the best approach would be to achieving this effect.

I've already locked things down as far as the server-side stuff is concerned, the servlet can't serve the pages without the proper auth, can't process any of the endpoints over HTTP, etc so I'm not concerned as far as server-side security.

One of my ideas was to design something to serve a GET request on /api/authLevel to return the auth level of the user currently logged in to return some plain-text "user", "operator", "admin" style values.

This way, I could do the fetch from React to obtain the value of this result and store that in the state of my app. But then I was thinking, since the user has to login before the React content is even served up, why can't I send that property along with the initial page being served?

In that vein, I was thinking it would make more sense to include the authorization level in a custom HTTP header but I'm unsure of how to even obtain that without React first issuing the request?

If I could do that I think that'd be easiest but I'm unsure of how to obtain that initial header value since React isn't even mounted until after the serving of the index.

Any suggestions? Required best-practices reading I should do? :)

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your goals, but it sounds like you'll want to do some research into server side rendering.  To lock down components (assuming it's ok to send the view logic to authorized areas -- it normally is), most use a higher order component wrapper.  E.g. <Authenticated><AdminPanel /></Authenticated>  If you're using a router, you can send the user to another route if unauthorized

Comment: Basically all of my authentication is handled outside of the React application, but when I'm serving my React app from my servlet I want to inform the application of the authentication "level" of the user currently logged-in as.